# sklearn's imputer reducing columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm wondering if anyone can help explain a weird behavior I'm seeing with sklearn's interativeImputer.

```
imputer = IterativeImputer(max_iter=100)
print("dateframe shape ", dataframe.shape)
tempDF = imputer.fit_transform(dataframe)
print("imputer shape: ", tempDF.shape)
```

I assume the shape would stay the same but the results are:

```
dateframe shape  (1978, 100)
imputer shape:  (1978, 91)
```

I found this error when I was converting the numpy array sklearn returns back into a pandas df

```
tempDF = pd.DataFrame(tempDF, index=dataframe.index, columns=dataframe.columns)
```

Any suggestions of what I can do to keep the original shape when using imputer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happenes probably because some of your coloms have everywhere `NaN`, I created a small example for you followed the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer.html):

```
from sklearn.experimental import enable_iterative_imputer
from sklearn.impute import IterativeImputer
imp_mean = IterativeImputer(random_state=0)
import numpy as np
imp_mean.fit([[7, 2, np.nan], [4, np.nan, np.nan], [10, 5, np.nan]])
X = [[7, 2, np.nan], [4, np.nan, np.nan], [10, 5, np.nan]]
imp_mean.transform(X)
array([[ 7.      ,  2.      ],
       [ 4.      , -0.999998],
       [10.      ,  5.      ]])
```

so if all is `Nan`the IterativeImputer has no `idea how to fit and transform it.
The original example in the docs end ups with (3,3) shape.